# Search form to search and fetch data from two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables ITEMS and  BARCODE each table is related to the other by column "id".

For example

ITEMS table has

```
id    Name    
1     Deodorant 1
```

BARCODE table has

```
id     barcode
1      56654397547
```

How to perform search by typing Barcode code in search form to display the product name using PDO?

I am not familiar with PDO and have basic knowledge with sql

EDIT : Sorry for not explaining the question correctly, the DB is a Point of sale "POS" DB and i am trying to build a search form to scan products barcode to view it's price on remote location.

this is the db connection code with a simple fetch for two tables :

```
    <?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=Marketing", "sa", "");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch (Exception $se)
    {
    die ( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
    }
    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS";
    $getResults = $conn->prepare( $tsql);
    $getResults->execute();
    $results = $getResults->fetchALL (PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row['ITEM_ID'].'  '.$row['ITEM_NAME'];
    echo '<br>'; }  
    ?>
```

Tables construction like so

ITEMS table

```
ITEM_ID   ITEM_NAME 
0         Deodorant 1
1         Deodorant 2
2         Shampoo
```

BARCODE table

```
ITEM_ID   BARCODE   PRICE_1
2         616161    $2
0         515151    $4
1         414141    $3
```

I want to build a form in HTML that has a POST field to search Barcode and display the ITEM NAME & PRICE_1

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also the expected result!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jarlh Post updated sorry for insufficient info

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `ITEMS` and `BARCODE` based on `id` column and get the `Name`

```
SELECT i.Name FROM ITEMS i JOIN BARCODE b 
ON
i.id=b.id 
WHERE
b.barcode = '56654397547';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired query is:

```
SELECT i.ITEM_NAME, b.PRICE_1 FROM BARCODE b 
LEFT JOIN ITEMS i ON i.ITEM_ID = b.ITEM_ID 
WHERE b.BARCODE = '616161';
```

Comment: Post updated, the DB belongs to a POS system we can't edit it's infrastructior